# Powershell - how to declare an array for use with += operator

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach, powershell-3.0

I can intuitively figure out most languages, but apparently not Powershell.

I want to create an array of arrays (this will contain disk directories and a count so later I can verify we have at least that many files).

From that array of arrays, I want to pull out a single array of just the directory names so I can pass it to Get-ChildItem.

```
$DirInfo = @('d:\Work',2),
            ('d:\Temp',3) 

$DirNameArray=@()                     #declare empty array 
foreach ($item in $DirInfo) 
  {
    $DirNameArray += , $item[0]       #tried with and without the comma here 
    Write-Host 'Loop1 '  $item[0] 
  }

write-host $DirNameArray.count

#Let's Verify what we got so we know how many items we have in our array 
Write-Host "Verify with a loop"
foreach ($dir in $DirNameArray) 
  {
    Write-Host 'Loop2:'  $dir
  }

Write-Host "Verify the other way"
Write-Host $DirNameArray
```

Actual Results:

```
Loop1  d:\Work
Loop1  d:\Temp
1 
Verify with a loop
Loop2: d:\Workd:\Temp
Verify the other way
d:\Workd:\Temp
```

What I don't understand is why Loop2 didn't execute twice.
It looks like the =+ is just stringing together the values instead of adding a new item to my array called $DirNameArray.

I'm still utterly baffled, one file I created does this and gives me the expected results:

```
$a = "one","two"
Write-Host $a.count 

$a += "three" 
Write-Host $a.count
```

Results:

```
2
3
```

So if the above worked, why didn't my code work?

A second file I created does this - and I don't understand the results.  I even made the variable name different so I wouldn't be dealing with any prior definition or values of that variable:

```
$DirNameArray5="abc","def"
write-host $DirNameArray5.count

$DirNameArray5 += "xyz"
write-host $DirNameArray5.count
$DirNameArray5 += @("opq")
write-host $DirNameArray5.count
```

Results:

```
1
1
1

$DirNameArray7="abc","def"
write-host $DirNameArray7.count

$DirNameArray7 += "xyz"
write-host $DirNameArray7.count
$DirNameArray7 += @("opq")
write-host $DirNameArray7.count
```

Results:

```
2
3
4
```

So apparently, if you once define a variable as a string, it's hard to get Powershell to redefine it as an array.

But I still have my original question. How to define an empty array so I can add to it in a loop using the += operator.

```
$DirNameArray=@()
```

I finally used the .GetType() method to see what my variables actually were: 
    PS C:\Users\nwalters> $DirNameArray5.GetType()

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                   
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                   
True     True     String                                   System.Object                                                                              



PS C:\Users\nwalters> $DirNameArray7.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                   
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                   
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Bottom line - this is what I want to do - in as few lines of code as possible with no loop:

```
[string]$x=@()    # declare empty array 
Write-Host $x.GetType() 
$x += "one" 
$x += "two" 
Write-Host $x.count 
Write-Host $x
```

Actual Results

```
System.String
1
onetwo
```

Desired Results:

```
object[]  or string[]??? 
2
one two
```

Comment: This code worked for me (in PowerShell 2). Try adding a `write-host $DirNameArray.count` line between the loops. If $DirNameArray IS an array, then the Count property will show the number of elements.

Comment: Don't know if this is related to PowerShell's habit of 'flattening' arrays (my guess would be not) but if so, the go-to resource appears to be Keith Hill's blog article http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/09/24/effective-powershell-item-8-output-cardinality-scalars-collections-and-empty-sets-oh-my/

Comment: andyb the .count shows 1, which is further proof it is not adding to my array, but just adding string-data onto the end of the string. I read the blog, not sure I got anything out of it to help here.

Comment: Also tried   $DirNameArray +=  @($item[0])    same issue.

Comment: I think my true issue is how to totally wipe out a variable.  I have closed and re-opened the ISE tool, and I see variables still have the values of when I left.  I think my $DirNameArray still has some hold-over from a prior run.

Comment: Ditch ISE and use PowerGui. This has a 'reset runspace' function. Alternatively, you should be able to use something like `remove-variable` see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849935.aspx

Comment: I agree, time to move to something better.  However, still need to know how to define an empty array so I can use the += to add to it in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Powershell will not let you create an empty array, or let you empty an array down to nothing (with one exception). There are two ways I have discovered to work around this issue:

Method 1: Use `-OutVariable` to a new variable name to create an array with your input

```
Example: gci C:\TestDir1 -OutVariable test
```

Using the `.GetType()` method returns:

```
$test.GetType()


    Directory: C:\TestDir1


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                             
----                -------------         ------ ----                                             
-a----        4/20/2020  11:36 AM           8015 Test1.xls                                        
-a----        6/26/2020  12:59 PM              0 test2.txt                                        

Module                     : CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary
Assembly                   : mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
                             PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
TypeHandle                 : System.RuntimeTypeHandle
DeclaringMethod            : 
BaseType                   : System.Object
UnderlyingSystemType       : System.Collections.ArrayList
FullName                   : System.Collections.ArrayList
```

This will create a new variable named $test that is an array (since there are multiple items in it). `$test.gettype()` shows the object as an array.

Method 2: Explicitly declare an array with two dummy objects and then remove both dummy objects.

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$array = "value1", "value2"
$array.remove("value1")
$array.remove("value2")
```

Using the gettype method will still show `$test` is an array even though it is empty:

```
> $test.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                               
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                               
True     True     ArrayList                                System.Object
```

The array will now be completely empty and can be used to store any new input. This doesn't work unless you explicitly name the variable type like I did in my example (not sure why). Example shown below:

```
$test = "value1", "value2"

$test.Remove("value1")

Exception calling "Remove" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."
At line:3 char:1
+ $test.Remove("value1")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupportedException
```

P.S. I know this is an old thread, but it is unanswered and I just came upon this issue myself so I am answering it for anyone else that searches this issue.

Comment: This is an exceptional first answer. I really appreciate that you didn't _just_ include code, but also provided a careful explanation along with results. That's exactly what we look for on Stack Overflow. Welcome to the community!

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! Glad to be part of the community as a contributor.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is tested on two different computers, both with PowerShell 2.0. Can you try this and post results.

```
# declare an empty array
$var = @()
write-host "var.count = '$($var.count)'  var.type ='$($var.GetType())'  var.type.BaseType = '$($var.GetType().BaseType)'"

# add a single item
$var += "single item"
write-host "var.count = '$($var.count)'  var.type ='$($var.GetType())'  var.type.BaseType = '$($var.GetType().BaseType)'"

# add an array
$var += , @("array 1 - item 1","array 1 - item 2")
write-host "var.count = '$($var.count)'  var.type ='$($var.GetType())'  var.type.BaseType = '$($var.GetType().BaseType)'"

# display the 'single item'
write-host "single item = '$($var[0])'"

# display first element of array item
write-host "first element of array item = '$($var[1][0])'"
```

gives me

```
var.count = '0'  var.type ='System.Object[]'  var.type.BaseType = 'array'
var.count = '1'  var.type ='System.Object[]'  var.type.BaseType = 'array'
var.count = '2'  var.type ='System.Object[]'  var.type.BaseType = 'array'
single item = 'single item'
first element of array item = 'array 1 - item 1'
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm confused on two things: 1) what is difference between [string]$x=@() and $x=@(),  2) My DirNameArray program runs fine today, but failed yesterday.  I have no idea why.  I still think I must have some old variables in memory that are not get cleared out properly.

Comment: You can reset a variable by as follows 'remove-varable VarName` e.g. `Remove-Variable DirNameArray`. To prove var is gone, use `get-variable (varname)`.

Comment: Did you try the code I posted? If so, did you get same result as me?